# Android: How to kill a runnable thread

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, runnable

I am trying to setup a timer on a different thread for my little android game. when the time is up I want to show a game over dialog. 
the problem is when time is up, game over dialog keeps being generated, that is why I think the thread is running and it is not ended. Can some one please give me some hints on what I am doing wrong?

```
    m_handler = new Handler();
    m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(timeleft>=0)
            {
                timerTextView.setText("seconds remaining: " +Integer.toString(timeleft));
                timeleft--;
            }
            else
            {
                timerTextView.setText("Done!!!?");
                m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask); // cancel run

                createGameOverDialog();

        }
            m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);
        }
    };
    m_handlerTask.run();


}
```

Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

You're never returning in the ending block, so it always continues posting the delay:

```
    m_handler = new Handler();
    m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(timeleft>=0)
            {
                timerTextView.setText("seconds remaining: " +Integer.toString(timeleft));
                timeleft--;
            }
            else
            {
                timerTextView.setText("Done!!!?");
                m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask); // cancel run
                createGameOverDialog();
                return; //here
        }
            m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);
        }
    };
    m_handlerTask.run();


}
```